# Lucene writing from web request

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, web, lucene

I'm looking to implement Lucene for a webapp I'm working on and I'm more or less looking for a "best practice".

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a web request come in (via an `ajax` post) and add a doc to my `lucene` index with the information posted.

However, what I'm unsure of is:
Can I run `lucene` in the context of a web request or do I need to run it separately and have my requests write to a folder (which the separate `lucene` would monitor and load docs based on the file)

I've been doing allot of searching into how to achieve this but I'm not finding many/any results so I think I totally off here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the deciding factor here is just what sort of response time do you want users (or the ajax client) to see, and whether you want to guarantee that when the request completes the document has actually been added.  That said, adding a document to a Lucene index is usually relatively fast (less than a few milliseconds is not unusual) you can probably do it in the context of the web request unless you have extremely strict timing requirements.  Of course, indexing speed will depend on the document size and the complexity of your tokenizing and analysis.

(And if the request just queues a document for later indexing, then the client doesn't know for sure whether it was indexed when the response comes back.  You would have to come up with some other way of letting clients know when a document was indexed or if there was an error indexing it, if they care about that.)

One thing you may want to do consider is periodically optimizing the index to keep space requirements small and queries fast.  Optimizing can take a long time, so it's not something you want to do after every addition, and you probably don't want to do it in the context of a web request.